# How do I use wai-handler-devel with a simple wai application

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-wai

I have the basic "hello world" application setup using wai, and would like to use wai-handler-devel, but am unsure how to go about it and can't find any examples of it in usage on a wai project.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 () -- Just for an orphan instance

app :: Application
app _ = return $ responseLBS
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    "Hello, World!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
    run 8080 app
```

What do I need to do to get wai-handler-devel working with a basic wai app?

Note: 
There is a fix here ( https://gist.github.com/1499226) i f you run into issues with "wai-handler-devel: command not found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wai-handler-devel's [Hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-devel) says that it should be invoked from the command-line like so:

```
$ wai-handler-devel <port> My.App.Module myApp
```

and that your application's type must look like this:

```
myApp :: (Application -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

In this case, you should define `myApp` as follows:

```
myApp :: (Application -> IO ()) -> IO ()
myApp handler = handler app
```

although you may want to inline `app` entirely:

```
myApp :: (Application -> IO ()) -> IO ()
myApp handler = handler $ \_ -> return $ responseLBS
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    "Hello, World!"
```

The type is like this so that you can do initialisation on start-up and the like in `IO`. I suggest reading the [SmallApp](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-handler-devel/SmallApp.hs) and [FullApp](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-handler-devel/FullApp.hs) examples from wai-handler-devel's git repository; the latter is especially helpful, as it has debug output showing the flow of the code during a reload, and shows how to integrate a long-running database connection.

The [run script](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-handler-devel/run-fullapp.hs) for the FullApp example also shows how to use wai-handler-devel programmatically, including manually specifying Hamlet template dependencies (which the `wai-handler-devel` command-line tool [determines automatically](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-handler-devel/wai-handler-devel.hs#L32)).

You should then be able to rewrite your `main` as follows:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
    myApp (run 8080)
```

Of course, you could just as easily pass the `run` function from [wai-handler-fastcgi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-fastcgi), [wai-handler-scgi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-scgi) or even [wai-handler-webkit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-webkit).

Comment: When running wai-handler-devel from the command line I hit a "wai-handler-devel: command not found" error.

Comment: I upgraded Haskell over the weekend, I wonder if that has broken the command. Quite strange.

Comment: Try `~/.cabal/bin/wai-handler-devel` — if that works, then you need to add `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your `$PATH`. Failing that, you might want to try `cabal install`ing it again.

Comment: OK. I don't have ~/.cabal/bin at all. I might reinstall Haskell and start again.

Comment: Found it in $HOME/Library/Haskell/bin and added to path