# How can I set up wai-handler-devel with Scotty to have automatic code reloading?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-wai

I've been playing around with the [Scotty web framework](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty) and tried to make it work with [wai-handler-devel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-devel) to enable code reloading. Here's an example app

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Example where

import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Network.Wai
import Web.Scotty

handler :: ScottyM ()
handler = get "/:word" $ do
  beam <- param "word"
  html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 handler
```

the problem here is that `wai-handler-devel` expects to get an `(Application -> IO ()) -> IO ()` function to make things work, but in this case I only have `ScottyM ()` and `IO ()`. There are a few functions in the [`Web.Scotty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.7.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html) and [`Web.Scotty.Trans`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.7.1/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html) packages, namely the following

`scottyApp :: ScottyM () -> IO Application` this can turn our `handler` into `IO Network.Wai.Application`, which is closer to what `wai-handler-devel` expects, but not exactly.

There's also `scottyAppT ::` [type signature omitted](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.7.1/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html#g:1) ... but in this case I'm not even sure how to read the type signature.

What I've found is that there are [some examples of using `wai-handler-devel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462493/how-do-i-use-wai-handler-devel-with-a-simple-wai-application) on a WAI application alone, but I just don't know how to convert the Scotty application to a WAI application with the required signature.

I also wanted to ask that since `wai-handler-devel` is being deprecated in favor of `yesod-bin`, is that supposed to replace it even for simple WAI/Scotty applications like this, or is yesod-bin just for yesod applications?

Comment: Great questions, I'd like to know the answers as well. I'm going to try to get the handler working with a simple Scotty app in the next few days. I'll keep this question in mind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually turned out to be rather easy. Say that the application has a `router` function which has the type of `router :: ScottyM ()`.

The way you'd run the app normally is

```
main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 router
```

the only thing needed to make this work with `wai-handler-devel` is to define another function, say `dev`, that looks like this

```
dev :: (Application -> IO ()) -> IO ()
dev h = scottyApp router >>= h
```

After that you just need to run `wai-handler-devel 3000 MyModule dev` and it all works perfectly :)